# How do I get the input from stdout when doing getOpts

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int o;
    int a;
    int b = 1;

    while ((o = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b")) != -1) {
        switch (o) {
           case 'a' :
                a = atoi(optarg);
                break;


            case 'b' :
                b = 0;
                break;
            default :
                printf("Error\n");
                exit(1);
        }
    }

    if(optind != 2) {
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

}
```

assuming this is legal:

```
$ gcc -Wall fileAbove.c
$ ./a.out -a14 -b hi
$ ./a.out -a14 hi
$ ./a.out -b hi
```

Everything above is legal. How do I find the standard output ?

```
$ echo hello | ./a.out -a14 -b 
hello

$ echo hello | ./a.out -a14
hello
```

Like how do I know there is no "./a.out -a10 -b (this part)", if there isn't that part we process the standard output.

Comment: You mean standard *input*?

Comment: yes standard input sorry

Comment: What is the requirement and what isn't working?

Comment: "$ echo hello | ./a.out -a14" doesn't print hello as I want it too, for example. Is there a way to find out if a program doesn't have any arguments apart from command options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this if statement:

```
if(optind != 2) { ... }
```

`optind` will be exactly 2 if you're using only arg `-a` **OR** arg `-b` (and not both), because then you have one argument and once you read it, the next opt index is 2. Then your if condition is false.

Comment: I guess you mean `if (argc+1 != optind) `. I'm not sure what are your requirements so it's hard to tell, but sounds very easy just to try and see if then you're getting the results you expect to get.